# Can I put a splitButton control on the QAT of Word 2010?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I have added some custom buttons on the QAT of the Word 2010 using RibbonX, I also want to use splitButton to group a few buttons, but I found the QAT cannot display custom splitButtons.

Part of the RibbonX code:

```
<splitButton idQ="x1:BookmarkButtons" visible="true"><button idQ="x1:InsertLinkedImportantContentBookmark" onAction="InsertLinkedImportantContentBookmark" label="Insert linked important content bookmark" imageMso="NewSketchpadTool" visible="true"/><menu idQ="x1:OtherBookmarkButtons" visible="true"><button idQ="x1:InsertLinkedImportantContentBookmark" imageMso="NewSketchpadTool" onAction="InsertLinkedImportantContentBookmark" label="Insert linked important content bookmark" visible="true"/><button idQ="x1:BoldAndInsertLinkedImportantContentBookmark" imageMso="NewSketchpadTool" onAction="BoldAndInsertLinkedImportantContentBookmark" label="Bold and insert linked important content bookmark" visible="true"/></menu></splitButton>
```

while I import the RibbonX file using the Word dialog, there is no error, all controls work well except for splitButton, which does not appear on the QAT. I want to know whether I can put a custom splitButton control on the QAT of Word 2010. If not, how can I group some functions together? Thanks a lot for your answor.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately a `splitButton` cannot be added to the QAT. The best you can do is create a set of `seperator` to seperate your controls from others. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd948879.aspx for more details on the QAT.